# Whats wrong with my proof that there are uncountably many rationals in $\Bbb R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhbaG.jpg

First of all, I know that this proof can't be right as there are countably many rationals in $\Bbb R$.

Alas, I seemed to have convinced myself otherwise. If the picture is too blurry, my life of reasoning is:

1.) For every $x, y \in \Bbb R$ such that $x < y$, there exists a rational
number $r$ such that $x < r < y$

2.) Create a bijective function that pairs two irrational numbers with a rational number between them.

3.) There are uncountably many irrationals, so there are uncountably many pairs, so there are uncountably many rationals we can associate with each pair of irrationals.

Comment: I'm with you on step 1.  Step 2. is where I lose you.  You certainly haven't given much evidence that it is possible for such a function to be "bijective".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2.) Create a bijective function that pairs two irrational numbers with a rational number between them.

This is not bijective. Between $-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt 2$ there is the rational number $0$. Also between $-2 \sqrt 2$ and $2 \sqrt 2 $ there is the rational number...$0$.

So it is not a bijection, merely a surjection. This proves that $|\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q |\ge |\Bbb Q|$, but we know that. :)

Comment: What if every interval bounded by two irrationals are mutually disjoint?

Comment: @SZHOU Irrationals are dense too, so you wouldn't have every irrational.

Comment: @SZHOU:Then you will only have countably many such intervals. Bottom line: If you use all pairs of irrationals, uncountably many such pair will have to share a rational. If you try to avoid sharing, then you can have at most countably many pairs.